# What are the best alternatives to Unity Asset Store for publishing game assets?

Tags: assets, publishing

I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask this so go easy on down-voting

Comment: Welcome to [gamedev.se]! As you thought, the format of this site is not the best fit for this type of question.

Comment: Welcome! Regarding closure, questions asking for a "list of X" (in this cases, place to publish assets) are not considered to be [on-topic](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). If after checking the [help](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help) you're still not sure if your question is on-topic here, your welcome to ask about it in [meta](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/) or [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19/game-development). Asking the community to go easy on down votes isn't a substitute for checking the guidelines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out these sites:

1. https://itch.io
2. https://www.gamedevmarket.net
3. https://craftpix.net

gamedevmarket allows you to sell your assets but I'm not sure of the rest, just check them out, I'm pretty sure they will help

Comment: cgtrader.com is another one